# How to move DIV's (sidebar) with if/else checker?

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I have three DIV's in a container, like so:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="left">left</div>
  <div class="center">click me</div>
  <div class="right">right</div>
  <div class="spacer"></div>
</div>

body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
}

.left, .center, .right {
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid black;
  float: left;
  padding: 10px;
}

.left, .right {
  width: 25%;
}

.center {
  width: 50%;
}

.right {
  right: -999px;
  transition: right 0.5s ease-out;
}

.left {
  left: -999px;
  transition: right 0.5s ease-out;
}

.spacer {
  clear: both;
}
```

I've already coded it so that when you click on the .center DIV, the two sidebars (.left & .right) DIV's move into place. I used this code:

```
$('.center').click(function(){
      $('.right').animate({"right": "0"});
      $('.left').animate({"left": "0"});
    }
});
```

What I want to do is write it so that AFTER they move into place, I can click on the .center DIV again and they'll move out like a sidebar does. My idea is to use an if/else checker so that it knows what state the DIV's are in.

I'm fairly new to Javascript and reading the if/else samples on Google only gets me more confused.

Any help? Thanks!

Comment: Use either animate or transition please.

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to rely on the animate complete property...

http://api.jquery.com/animate/

EDIT: I've updated to match your code...

```
$( ".center" ).click(function() {
  $( ".right" ).animate({"right": "0"}, 5000, function() {
    // Place the code you want to perform once animation is complete here.
  });
});
```

You have a few options here - you could set a flag in the animation complete block for instance...

```
 var complete = false;
 $( ".center" ).click(function() {
  $( ".right" ).animate({"right": "0"}, 5000, function() {
    complete = true;
  });
});
```

EDIT based on on comments...

```
$('.center').click(function(){
      $('.right').animate({"right": "100px"});
      $('.left').animate({"left": "100px"});
});
```

Comment: I tried it but for some reason it doesn't work. I tried it with this code and it works, just that I think the 'alert()' isn't a good solution. It works though. What do you think? 

var complete = false;
$('.center').click(function(){
  if (complete==false) {
    $('.right').animate({"right": "0"});
    $('.left').animate({"left": "0"});
    complete=true;
    alert(Done);
  }
});

$('.center').click(function(){
  if (complete==true) {
    $('.right').animate({"right": "-999px"});
    $('.left').animate({"left": "-999px"});
    complete=false;
  }
});